# Automapper map an inherited object to a child

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following classes:

Source:

```
public class Source
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ChildBase Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildBase
{

}

public class Child : ChildBase
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

For the map I'm trying to create, I want to map from `Source` to `Parent`. The property on the `Parent` is defined as `ChildBase` but I want the map to actually map to `Child`. How can I get the mapper to map to `Child`?

I have a simple map defined as:

```
CreateMap<Source, Parent>()
  .ForMember(d => d.Child, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s));

CreateMap<Source, Child>();
```

But obviously this is trying to look for a map with the destination of `ChildBase`. I tried casting the destination to be `Child` but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try .Include<>() or .IncludeBase<>() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the custom [ValueResolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) in AutoMapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Parent>()
    .ForMember(p => p.Child, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => new Child { Amount = s.Amount }));
```

If you want to re-use this logic, you can put the code into a class instead of a lambda expression.

```
class SourceToChildValueResolver : ValueResolver<Source, Child>
{
    protected override Child ResolveCore(Source source)
    {
        return new Child { Amount = source.Amount };
    }
}

//register the resolver
CreateMap<Source, Parent>()
    .ForMember(p => p.Child, o => o.ResolveUsing<SourceToChildValueResolver>());
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a defined map rather than manually mapping it? Also, not sure if it's because I'm not using the static version but I have to cast the object in the `Resolve`: `s => new Child { Amount = ((Source)s.Value)Amount }` as `s` is a `ResolutionResult`

Comment: @ADringer Are you using AutoMapper 5.0+? See my edit.